# When to use kernelspace and when to use userspace?

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, embedded, driver, linux

Suppose I have an embedded device like a rapsberry pi and would need to communicate with a module over e.g. i2c. When would it be a good choice to try to communicate with the module by writing kernelspace code? 
I know that there are libraries available that allow you to communicate with the module via i2c by writing userspace code. When would you rather go for the latter solution?

Comment: If you don't know the answer, the answer's userspace.

Answer (score 6):

Userspace whenever possible, kernelspace where necessary.

When might it be necessary to use kernelspace? When there are hard latency requirements or the existing driver architecture is inadequate.

Why is it preferred to use userspace? It's considerably easier to debug, safer if it crashes, more portable to other systems and easier to install.

Comment: Just to make sure, is using an RTOS considered as userspace or kernelspace? I think that using an RTOS may help you to meet timing requirements and such so you don't have to use kernelspace that much. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @trilolil Ok, you seem to have a basic lack of knowledge on what an OS, what kernel- and userspace are.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am sort of an autodidact when it comes to embedded linux and stuff. In case it is you: why downvote?

Comment: Safer if it crashes? Compared with what? A userspace program that has i2c and possibly root access is no way safe even when it doesn't crash.

Answer (score 0):

Use userspace code whenever possible. It's much simpler to debug and more portable.

The main reasons implementing a driver in kernelspace is your driver needs interrupts, which may be true for example for I²C touch controllers, or your driver should fit in into an existing kernel subsystem – again, I²C touch controllers come to mind, but also hardware sensors that should be evaluated by kernel code.